# what is data transmission rate in bits per second ?

Tags: networking, network-programming, neural-network, network-security

suppose that data are stored on 4.7 Mbytes CDs that weight 50 grams each.suppose that an airplane carries 10^4 kg of these CDs at a speed of 1500 km/h over a distance of 5000 km.what is data transmission rate in bits per second of this system?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the tags you included. Also, this must be a homework question. Last of all, this is the weirdest question... ever.

Answer (score 0):

I would not call this 'data-transmission', but:

`Amount of CD's = 10^4 / 0.05 = 2e5`

`Amount of bits = 4.7e6 * 8 * amount of CD's = 7.52e12`

`Seconds to carry data = 5000e3 / (1500/3.6) = 12000 seconds`

`(7.52 * 10^12)/ 12000) = 0.6Gbits/s`